# Google Place Details API returns only one photo in the photos array

Tags: google-places-api

All my maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json calls return only one photo in photos[].

Does anybody have an example of a placeId whose details query return more than one photo?

I've even changed lat/lng to SF's Financial District and queried the details for the first set of restaurants returned by the search API and still...all follow-up place details calls return with only one item in the photos[].

I am either missing something or there is no other data.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you right now.
Looks like Google has changed their DB after the last change (placeid addition).
This might be temporary, but so far, I don't think it's our fault.

Comment: I tried ChIJoyoBvjx-j4ARNUWlMkjGUL4 (pushbit's recommended place_id) and the call returns multiple photos - it's not us. Thank you.

Comment: UPDATE: it looks that our Google human friends fixed the API. The photos[] is being populated today with more than one image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `place_id` that returns multiple photos. `ChIJoyoBvjx-j4ARNUWlMkjGUL4`